# What type of certificate is this?

Tags: elliptic-curves, certificates

I have been reading papers about authentication in VANETS and some of them mention a certificate that a trusted authority generates for a vehicle and has the following form:
$${C_{V_i}}=S_{TA}+H(PID_{V_i}|PID_{TA}|P_{TA}|P_{V_I})*x_i$$
Here $S_{TA}$ is a secret that belongs to Trusted Authority.
$H()$ is a hash function.
$PID_{V_i}$ is the pseudo-identity of vehicle $V_i$.
$PID_{TA}$ is the pseudo-identity of $TA$.
$P_{TA}$ is the public key of $TA$.
$P_{V_i}$ is the public of of vehicle $V_i$.
and $x_i$ is a random secret generated by the $TA$.
the form is TA's secret plus some hash value times another random secret. They also mention that they are working with elliptic curve cryptography for their works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a certificate, this looks to be part of an [Ed25519 signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Summary).

The value in question is usually denoted $S$ rather than $C$. The long-term and ephemeral secrets $S_{TA}$ and $x_i$ respectively are reversed from their usual usage ($r$ and $s$ in the usual Ed25519 equation are the ephemeral and long-term secrets. The value can only be verified if also presented with a curve point $R=x_iG$ and if there is a system owners public signing key $P=S_{TA}G$. If this is the case then the verfifier can check that
$$C_VG=P+H({\rm identifiers/keys})R.$$